# How to join two query result and filter out the data based on the condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, qsqlquery

I am running two sql queries which is giving some output. I want to combine them and filter out the result based on the requirement.

Explaination -

query 1:

```
select `Project Number` from vw_onco_pharma onco_pharma union select `Project Number` from vw_onco_cell_gene cell_gene union select `Project Number` from vw_non_onco_cell_gene onco_cell_gene union select `Project Number` from vw_non_onco_pharma non_onco_pharma union select `Project Number` from vw_plasma_protein plasma_protein
```

Output 1:

```
Project Number
S100
S100
S200
S300
S300
S300
S400
S400
```

Query 2:
select `Project Number` from FCT_HTA_ONC_NONONC_PGMS;

Output 2:

```
Project Number
S100
S200
S200
S300
S300
S300
S500
```

Now I have to convert Output1 & Output2 in below format:

```
Output 1 :                          Output 2 :
Project Number    Count            Project Number    Count
S100              2                S100              1    
S200              1                S200              2   
S300              3                S300              3
S400              2                S500              1
```

Now match the Output 1 & Output 2 and print the differences-

Final Output:

```
Project Number
S100
S200
S400
S500
```

Comment: 1) Add GROUP BY to the queries and calculate COUNTs additionally. 2) Use subqueries as CTEs. 3) Add 3rd CTE which gathers all project numbers which are present in at least one table (UNION). 4) Join first 2 CTEs to 3rd CTE (LEFT) in outer query and select rows where COUNTs are not equal (or one of them is NULL).

Comment: Hi @Akina , Could you please provide me the sample query which help me?

Comment: *Output 1* cannot be obtained by shown query - UNION will collapse duplicated numbers. You should use UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH
-- first query, UNION ALL used instead of single UNION 
cte1 AS (select `Project Number` from vw_onco_pharma onco_pharma 
         union all
         select `Project Number` from vw_onco_cell_gene cell_gene 
         union all
         select `Project Number` from vw_non_onco_cell_gene onco_cell_gene 
         union all
         select `Project Number` from vw_non_onco_pharma non_onco_pharma 
         union all
         select `Project Number` from vw_plasma_protein plasma_protein),
-- count the amounts for 1st query
cte2 AS (SELECT `Project Number`, COUNT(*) cnt
         FROM cte1
         GROUP BY `Project Number`),
-- 2nd query, amounts counting added
cte3 AS (select `Project Number`, COUNT(*) cnt
         from FCT_HTA_ONC_NONONC_PGMS
         GROUP BY `Project Number`),
-- gathering all projects
cte4 AS (SELECT `Project Number`
         FROM cte1
         UNION 
         SELECT `Project Number`
         FROM cte3)
-- get final data
SELECT `Project Number`
FROM cte4
LEFT JOIN cte2 USING (`Project Number`)
LEFT JOIN cte4 USING (`Project Number`)
WHERE cte2.cnt IS NULL
   OR cte4.cnt IS NULL
   OR cte2.cnt <> cte4.cnt;
```